# CNN for detecting changes in gradient? (depth map)

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I have a problem wherein I am trying to find changes in gradient in a depth map while ignoring noise and artifacts. I am using this to detect 'dropoffs' in drivable surfaces that mostly show up in curbs. These edges can be quite hard to detect in a color image as both sides of the curb can have the same surface and, curb styles, colors, and orientation can vary widely between locations:

[image]

Hence, the decision to use a depth map.

While the changes in depth can be done with a fairly straightforward algorithm, ignoring (or at least recognizing) noise and artifacts is really difficult to do. My current approach is to simply shift the image by a few pixels, then subtract it from itself to reveal the rapid changes in gradient: [video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tLZlV2AfUKc)

This works really well until noise appears in the image:

[image]
[image]

After some research, I think the most robust way to detect these is to use a convolutional neural network (CNN). I have some experience with these in the past, but this seem to be a fairly unique problem as this is neither full segmentation or classification. The target for the output is quite small, and consistently labeling the images turns out to be really difficult:

[image]

**My question is** (if it's too broad please allow me to clarify): What labeling system/network could be used for such a task? And, am I actually correct in assuming that this is a job for a neural network?

Using Nvidia DIGITS and Caffe, I have tried these nets so far  (with out much luck):

- [DIGITS binary segmentation](https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/blob/master/examples/binary-segmentation)
- [Alexnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AlexNet)
- [HED net](https://github.com/s9xie/hed)

For my labeling techniques, I have tried two separate approaches:

Output edge segmentation (Same size as input)

[image]

Output grid classification (32x18 grid, filled if containing any edge)

[image]

In both cases, the resulting output is mostly gibberish, the loss is through the roof

Answer (score 1):

In light of the new information, I have the following suggestions. Both involve machine learning. Given the complexity of the real world, I believe in these cases, detecting the line using heuristics alone is going to be difficult.

### If you have sufficient data:

I think you should pose this as a deep learning based object detection problem directly. As you noted yourself "These edges can be quite hard to detect in a color image as both sides of the curb can have the same surface and, curb styles, colors, and orientation can vary widely between locations". Depth map is one useful feature, but a deep network will learn depth, along with all the other contextual cues that you indicated. Using a deep network on the depth map will not be as effective, since the input is already a lower dimension feature (as opposed to the RGB image). [Here](https://news.developer.nvidia.com/drive-labs-detecting-road-markings-and-landmarks-with-high-precision/) is an example of detecting lanes.

### If you don't have sufficient data:

Extract features such as depth, orientation of edges and any other feature that you think might be useful. Use algorithms such as SVMs or Random Forests to classify the line based on these features.

---

Old answer before edit:
What is the final application that you're looking to solve? The statement "trying to find changes in gradient in a depth map while ignoring noise and artifacts" is a bit ambiguous, since there are several gradient changes in the left side of the image that I'm not sure whether you care about or not.

This looks something like an autonomous driving dataset. If your goal is to detect say, lane lines or road boundaries, trying to detect that directly might be easier than trying to estimate depth.

If not, please let us know (as much as you can/allowed to) what the end goal is, since "noise" is subjective from one application to the next.